# How to disable send e-mail notification new comments for some posts

Tags: php

How to disable send e-mail notification new comments for some posts

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

You can use [notify_moderator](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/notify_moderator/) and [notify_post_author](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/notify_post_author/) filters to control whether or not the comment notification should be sent - to the moderator or comment author.

```
add_filter('notify_moderator', 'prefix_filter_sent_comment_notification', 10, 2);
add_filter('notify_post_author', 'prefix_filter_sent_comment_notification', 10, 2);
function prefix_filter_sent_comment_notification( bool $maybe_notify, int $comment_ID ) {
    $comment = get_comment($comment_ID);
    $comment_post = get_post($comment->comment_post_ID);
    // determine, if notification should sent or not
    // return true to send
    // to not, return false
    return some_logic_check( $comment_post ) ? false : $maybe_notify;
}
```